# Can Xcode (command-line) build an archive without a scheme?

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, compilation

I'm primarily a .NET developer but am trying to compile some applications for iOS using Xcode command-line tools.  My goal is to use the command-line to write a script to clone a repository, compile the code, and sign it with my iOS developer certificate.

However, when I clone a Git repository for an iOS/OSX application, it usually only contains a Xcode project file (and sometimes a workspace file).  When I try to use 'xcodebuild archive' it requires a scheme to be specified but 'xcodebuild -list' says that none exist.

What is the correct way to automatically generate these schemes from the command-line?

Comment: Xcode should create the default schemes on launch, so maybe you could try adding the command 'open YourProject.xcodeproj' to your script prior to the Xcode build command. Otherwise I do not think there is a way to create a scheme from the command line.